# no output with the pointer pointing to the strings

Tags: c

```
int main(){
 char a[80] = "Angus Declan R";
 char b[80];
 char *p,*q;
 p = a;
 q = b;
 while(*p != '\0'){
  *q++ = *p++;
 }
 *q = '\0';
 printf("\n p:%s q:%s \n",p,q);
 puts(p); //prints the string
 puts(q); //doesnt print the string
 return 0;
}
```

why the strings are not copied from p to q? when trying to print the q, it prints nothing

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reposition your pointers at the good position of the string before the display (so : p=a  and q=b).

```
int main(){
 char a[80] = "Angus Declan R";
 char b[80];
 char *p,*q;
 p = a;
 q = b;
 while(*p != '\0'){
  *q++ = *p++;
 }
 *q = '\0';
 p=a;
 q=b;
 printf("\n p:%s q:%s \n",p,q);
 puts(p); //prints the string
 puts(q); //doesnt print the string
 return 0;
}
```

Note : You are probably lucky that : puts(p); "Print the string" It's probably because a and b are stored consecutively. If you have done something like :

```
 char a[80] = "Angus Declan R";
 char c[80] = {"\0"}; //example
 char b[80];
```

the puts(p); would have print nothing aswell.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
p = a;
q = b;
```

again before

```
printf("\n p:%s q:%s \n",p,q);
 puts(p); //prints the string
 puts(q); //doesnt print the string
```

Because the `p` and `q` pointers are incremented in the `while` loop and they are not pointing any more in the beginning of the `a` and `b` char arrays

**BTW** and Just as remark:

You can replace this bloc of code

```
while(*p != '\0'){
  *q++ = *p++;
 }
 *q = '\0';
```

by

```
while(*q++ = *p++); // more simple ;-)
```

Answer (score 1):

`puts(p); //prints the string`

This is just luck due the particular case of the situation. Both `p` and `q` are at the end of their respective strings.

Comment: but how does puts(p) prints the string from the beginning of the pointer

Comment: @Angus In brief , given the addess of a string , puts() will , print all the characters , till it encounters '\0' , puts() then converts this to '\n'

Comment: @UmNyobe: For the comments its clear that as *p++ will be holding the character '\0' hence trying to print the p will produce no result. So Puts shouldnt have printed the string as it is now pointing to the address at the end of the string and not at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code fixed

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char a[80] = "Angus Declan R";
 char b[80];
 char *p,*q;
 p = a;
 q = b;
 while(*p != '\0')
  *q++ = *p++;
    *q++ = '\0';
 p = a;
 q = b;

 printf("\n p:%s q:%s \n",p,q);
 puts(p); 
 puts(q); 
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The strings are actually copied, and you can see that by typing this printf statement at the end:

```
 printf("\n a: %s b: %s \n", a, b);
```

However, you forgot something basic about the `++` operator. When you write `*q++ = *p++` , it's the same as writing:

```
q = q + 1;
p = p + 1;
*q = *p;
```

So, by the end of your loop, p and q are pointing at your null character, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: yeah correct. But as it was pointing to nul , how is it possible that puts() could able to print the whole string?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I run your code on my computer, it doesn't output the whole string.

Comment: with printf() it didnt output the whole string, but when tried with puts(p), got the output of the whole string .